Do "jusqu'au 6 octobre" and "until October 6th" mean the same thing?
The question is motivated by this one in the Politics community. In English until October 6th would exclude the date of October 6th itself (as far as I can judge - English is not my first language.) I speculated that a foreigner might misuse preposition until as meaning up to and including October 6th, if this is a common use of the equivalent preposition in their language.
I wonder, whether such a mistake could be made by a native French speaker - in other words, whether jusqu'au 6 october implies the date itself.

Same ambiguity in French & in English.  In French the use of inclus solves this ambiguity see « Du … au … » inclusion ou exclusion ?.

@None j'avais l'impression que quand il s'agit de promotions dans des magasins, jusqu'à inclut la date finale. J'apprécie votre avis.

Ça ne fait aucun doute que jusque est inclusif, voir le TLF :  « Exprime l'idée d'une limite spatio-temporelle (pour un espace que l'on parcourt ou pour une durée) ou bien l'idée de limite pour l'inclusion (effective ou imaginaire) dans un tout ». Mais beaucoup de francophones ont des doutes sur la question (par exemple). En ajoutant « inclus » on évite l’ambiguïté, du coup certains évoqueront le pléonasme !

Usually jusqu'au 6 octobre includes that day.
To make sure there is no ambiguity we often say jusqu'au 6 octobre inclus or jusqu'au 6 octobre [à] minuit.

